# How to send values to the cshtml template from C#

Tags: c#, razor

I have a cshtml template which is not from View. The template is from database. I have some dynamic values that should be updated to this cshtml template. How should I do it? I have the values also in the same class. How to pass that to template.

I see the values are not populated. I don't know how to pair this template and the model.

Here is my model:

```
var model = new UserDto();
 model.EmailAddress = email;
 model.UserId = userid;
```

My Template is stored as a file to a byte variable:

```
byte[] template = await GetTemplateFromDB(TemplateId);
```

My cshtml sample:

```
@model ...UserDto; 
 @using System.IO
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 ...
 ...
 ...
 <h1 class="heading helvetica_75">Certificate<br>of Membership</h1>
 <div class="info helvetica_65">This is to certify that</div>
 <div class="info-name helvetica_75">@Model.EmailAddress</div>
```

I expect the values to be passed to the template

Answer (score 0):

The thing is **Blazor** pages not always react at the data change in the variables and data model that you have.

In the case if page is not reacting to change automatically you just can use a command to make it update the view.

The command is:

```
this.StateHasChanged();
```

Where `this` refers to your current state of view.

The more expand example:

```
@code{
    public DataModel model = new DataModel();

    public async Task SomeAsync()
    {
        // Do some stuff with data
        // Adding new data to a model
        // Or getting something from a DB asynchronously
        model.Email = "Email@email.com";
        model.Name = "Tim";

        // call the view update
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Razor != Blazor. Razor Pages were around well before Blazor.

Comment: @AntonPolchenko The .cshtml page will not be under Views. It will be from Database and I need to update values in it

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `RazorView` class.

With html string in hand, write it to system %temp% path as text file, the use the below helper method to convert to to model binded view.This may seems complex, but will do the work for your code.

```
public string Parse(object ViewModel, ControllerContext controller,string tempFilePath,string template)
{
    try
    {
        var sb = new StringWriter();
        ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
        pathMapDictionary.Add(tempFilePath, template); // Add template to dictionary which virtual path provider will access
        var tempData = new TempDataDictionary();
        viewData.Model = ViewModel;
        var razor = new RazorView(controller, tempFilePath, null, false, null);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller, razor, viewData, tempData, sb);
        razor.Render(viewContext, sb);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exx)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Reference: http://blogs.quovantis.com/razor-engine-for-parsing-razor-pages-stored-as-string/